# Sorting a list of jobs to minimize objective function

Tags: python, optimization

So my problem is the following:
I've got a list of jobs that contain coordinates for a route my robot has to travel to get all its jobs done.
Now I want to sort the jobs so that it takes the robot a minimum of time to get everything done.
I've also defined an objective function, that sums up the way that it has to travel and that is to be minimized.

Now for my question: Which solving algorithm can I use for that problem? How do I express my problem so I can define proper design variables?
Thank you for all of your answers. Code below:

```
import pandas as pd

machine_positions = {1: [5, 10],
                     2: [50, 5],
                     3: [40, 20],
                     4: [60, 35],
                     5: [30, 35],
                     6: [20, 30]
                     }

def read_joblist(filename):
    # Lädt die Jobliste ein und bereitet diese auf in einzelne Jobs mit jeweils Anzahl 1
    # Übersetzt die Positionen der Maschinen in Koordinaten

    data = pd.read_csv(filename)
    refined_data = []
    shape = data.shape
    
    # Auftsplitten mehrerer Aufträge in mehrere Zeilen
    for i in range(shape[0]):

        # Auftrag vorbereiten zum Anhängen
        new_job = []
        new_job.append(data.loc[i][0])
        new_job.append(data.loc[i][1])

        # Übersetzen der Maschinennummern in Koordinaten
        new_job[0] = machine_positions.get(new_job[0])
        new_job[1] = machine_positions.get(new_job[1])

        # Auftrag so oft anhängen, wie Anzahl angegeben ist
        for j in range(data.loc[i]["Anzahl"]):
            refined_data.append(new_job)

    return refined_data


def objectivefunction_gestime(joblist_ordered):
    # summiert die nötigen Bewegungsfelder auf, die bei der Abarbeitung der Jobs anfallen
    time = 0
    for i in range(len(joblist_ordered)):
        # Aufsummieren des Betrags des Abstands in x und in y Richtung einzeln
        time += abs(int(joblist_ordered[i][1][0]) - int(joblist_ordered[i][0][0]))
        time += abs(int(joblist_ordered[i][1][1]) - int(joblist_ordered[i][0][1]))

        # Bei vorherigem Auftrag: Fahrt zwischen Aufträgen dazurechnen
        if i > 0:
            time += abs(int(joblist_ordered[i][0][0]) - int(joblist_ordered[i-1][1][0]))
            time += abs(int(joblist_ordered[i][0][1]) - int(joblist_ordered[i-1][1][1]))

    return time
```

Comment: This is really too broad of a question to get good answers.  What you have described above is the basis of the Traveling Salesman Problem (TSP).  This is a very common framework and there are lots of examples on the web on how to approach this.  Recommend you do a little research, try a few things, and re-post if you get stuck.

Comment: Thank you! The hint about the TSP was exactly what I needed! I will do my research now, thank you kind sir/madam